# Swift UserDefaults (2017)

Tags: xcode, currency, userdefaults

I'm new at Xcode and currently making an app, where you have an amount of "bananas / money", whereof you can flip a coin, and you either win 2x or lose your bet.
(Just for experience)

My game is fully working, I've now just decided, that I want to save the currency for whenever the app closes and starts; using NSUserDefaults.

I've set my NSUserDefaults up, and it's working. It's displaying the currency I had the last time I closed the app, and I can only bet between 0 and my currency. - Which is great!

However, even though my full currency is displaying, and that I can bet all of my total currency, the math behind it all is still struggling.
After the app closes it's putting the integer back to 0, because that's what I've declared ABOVE my viewDidLoad, when I was creating the variable.

Haven't understood? Lets say I have 30 bananas, and I'm about to bet 30 bananas. If I win, I'll have a total of 30 banans, and if I lose, I'll have -30 bananas. (The integer is for some reason set to 0)

I need a way to set the integer to my last saved; "currencySave".
- And I need a way of detecting if it's the first time the app has been opened; if yes, you'll have to start with a constant integer/currency.

Code:

All of my variables are ment to be in integers.

`betVar; the variable / value, that you're betting`

`currencyVar; the variable / value, that you're having. (Your cash)`

`currencySave; the name I've saved my integer into`

*Above viewDidLoad*

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var currencyVar = Int(0)
var betVar = Int(0)
```

*viewDidLoad*

```
let currencyVar = defaults.integer(forKey: "currencySave")

labelCurrency.text = String("$ \(currencyVar)")

betVar = 0
labelBet.text = String("$ \(betVar)")
```

*Slider, whereof you choose the bet-amount*

```
    let currencyVar = defaults.integer(forKey: "currencySave")
    let currentValue:String = String(Int(sender.value))
    betVar = Int(currentValue)!

    labelBet.text = currentValue


    labelSlider.maximumValue = Float(currencyVar)
    labelSlider.minimumValue = Float(0)
    labelBet.text = String("$ \(currentValue)")
```

*The math when winning a bet* (It takes the money from you as you click 'bet', that means, that nothing will happen, if you're losing.)

```
    self.currencyVar = self.currencyVar + self.betVar*2
    self.labelBet.text = String("\(self.betVar*2)")
    self.labelBet.textColor = UIColor.green
```

*My way of saving the integer*

```
    defaults.set(currencyVar, forKey: "currencySave")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating local variables with the same name so the property is ignored.

On the top level declare

```
var currencyVar = 0 // the compiler infer the Int type.
```

In `viewDidLoad` delete `let`

```
self.currencyVar = defaults.integer(forKey: "currencySave")
```

In *Slider, whereof you ...* use only the instance variable, **delete** the entire line

<strike>let currencyVar = defaults.integer(forKey: "currencySave")</strike>

and add `self` (although it's not required) to indicate the property.

```
labelSlider.maximumValue = Float(self.currencyVar)
```

Comment: THANKS! Thanks a lot for your fast reply. It really helped me out, and it's now totally working. Now that I have an experienced programmer on hand. What if I want to make some kind of a statistic system? Where I can see bets placed, best won and stuff.
I'm thinking of making an unique Userdefaults-keyword, that gonna get added by one for each time; a variable?
- You'll get my reputation, if I can find some way of honoring you.

Comment: For a statistics system which collects a bunch of data I'd prefer Core Data.

Comment: It's only those 3-4 statistics and not ment to become a graph or something. But if you say so, I'll google for Core Data, thanks for your answer!